# Why does Google BigQuery return duplicate rows but doesn't count them?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I do something like

```
select * from table where ID = 1234
```

I get 2 records.

if I run this query

```
select count(*) from table where ID = 1234
```

I get a count value of 1.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Right now, i don't know which answer is correct... do I have 1 record or 2 in the system?

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is possible if you have table with one row with id=1234, but this row has repeated field in it with two values.

BigQuery automatically flattens query results.
So below select just flattens out result and that's why you see two rows

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1234
```

whereas second statement below just counts rows, which is just one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ID = 1234
```

See below real example that ressembles your case

```
SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE ngram = 'to carry more'
```

above returns 241 rows, whereas below shows just 1 (one).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]  
WHERE ngram = 'to carry more'
```

This is my guess of what happens with you. To make it certain  - please provide schema of your table and maybe some data examples

You can read more about flattenning [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#flatten)

Comment: Note that COUNT(0) is a reliable way to count records if that's what you want.